# IE8 CurvyCorners.net Jquery Error exec(1...) is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

On a site I'm working on I'm using the CurvyCorners.net jQuery plugin, rounded corners work in Firefox/safari/ie7 compatibility mode... When I load the page in IE8 I get a JS error and the script does not execute. The link to the URL/Script in question is: http://tccyclist.com/modx/index.php?id=16

The error:`

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; HPNTDF; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Fri, 17 Dec 2010 18:48:46 UTC


Message: 'exec(...).1' is null or not an object
Line: 33
Char: 39
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js
```

`

A google search brought me to this:

```
 For those of you using curvycorners.js version 2.0.4 from the zip file and getting an IE8 error 'exec(...).1' is null or not an object ... you may want to check to see if your div has a microsoft.gradient filter on it. This version of the script breaks on line 1 char 13,871...

var n=filter?parseInt(/alpha\(opacity.(\d+)\)/.exec(filter)[1])

...is expecting you have applied an alpha (opacity) filter and breaks if you have applied a gradient! I didn't check this on the beta or SVN (I believe these versions fail silently).

HTH-
```

I am using a transparent PNG as the background-image, but I'm not sure how to handle what he's describing in there. Can anyone offer any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix here: http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/issues/detail?id=41